# Proving $\sqrt {P^ n}=P$ when $P$ is a prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am trying some assignments and I am struck on that.

If $R$ is a ring, and $A$ an ideal then $\sqrt{A}$ means  $\{a\in R| a^k \in A \text{ for some integer } k > 0\}$.

I need to show that if $P$ is a prime ideal in $R$ then $\sqrt{P^n} = P $.

I am sorry but I am unable to prove any of the inclusion.

$x\in \sqrt{P^n}$ implies that $\{x\in R| x^n \in P^n\}$. but I am unable to see how to use that it is a prime ideal to  prove x $\in  P$.

Comment: What about the other inclusion? That should be easy. Also, one of the $n$'s should be $m$ (a priori) in your last formula.

Comment: @Berci I don't think it is?

Comment: If $x\in P$, then $x^n\in P^n$, right?

Comment: @Avenger I wonder if maybe you had perhaps not completely understood the definition of the radical since you had not written it clearly.  To make it clearer, I changed what you wrote to not use "n" in both the definition of the radical and as the exponent for the power of the ideal. The first one quantifies over all $\mathbb N$ and the second one is a fixed $n$.

Comment: @Berci why it should hold, I am unable to see it. Can you please tell a rigorious proof?

Comment: By definition of $P^n$. What do you think this notation means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in P$, then $x^n\in P^n$ and so  $x\in \sqrt{P^n}$ whih proves the first inclusion.

If $x\in\sqrt{P^n}$ then there is some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x^m\in P^n$. But, by definition of product ideal, since $x^m\in P^n$ it is of the form
$x^m=p_{11}\dots p_{n 1}+\dots+p_{1 l}\dots p_{n l}$, where $p_{ij}\in P$ and $l\in\mathbb{N}$, so $x^m\in P$.  But $x^{m-1}x\in P$ implies (since $P$ is prime) that either $x\in P$ or $x^{m-1}\in P$. If $x\in P$ we are done, so we may assume $x^{m-1}\in P$. By induction on $m$ it is easy to check that $x\in P$, and so the inclusion is proved.

Comment: dear Marcos, it is not correct in general that $P\subseteq P^n$ for $n>1$. for example, consider the prime ideal $P=\langle 2\rangle$ of $\mathbb{Z}$. then $P^2=\langle 4\rangle$, so $P\nsubseteq P^2$.

Comment: You're right, now it should be ok.

Comment: indeed, +1! :) ${}$

Comment: @MarcosEscartínFerrer How does $x\in P$ implies that $x^n \in P^n$? Can you prove rigoriuosly?

Answer (score 2):

> $x\in \sqrt{P^n}$ implies that $\{x\in R| x^n \in P^n\}$.

Well, that's a valiant start. But what does it mean to "imply a set"? That is not what you mean.

The real implication of $x\in \sqrt{P^n}$ is, according to the definition, that $x^k\in P^n$ for some integer $k>0$.  But $P^n\subseteq P$... so then what?

Conversely, discussed in the comments, $x\in P$ implies $x^n\in P^n$, so that direction is already clear.  All that remains is for you to connect the dots in the previous hint I gave.